# show all tables in DB2 error CL END GET SET CALL DROP FREE HOLD LOCK OPEN WITH ALTER BEGIN

Tags: db2, weblogic12c

I tried to list the db2 tables but i get

> Token DB2 was not valid. Valid tokens: ( CL END GET SET CALL DROP FREE
>   HOLD LOCK OPEN WITH ALTER BEGIN. SQLState: 42601

Any updates ?

Comment: put you code here if you want help....

Comment: SELECT * FROM SYSIBM.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'infoL516';   IT LIst tables but , wha is the command to list colums.

Answer (score 0):

for list table you must use this:

```
select * from sysibm.systables
```

for list columns :

```
select * from sysibm.syscolumns
```

Comment: thnk you but this it list all and crash my db  example : 

SELECT * FROM SYSIBM.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'DETAIL';    
how to list colums inside details ?     TABLE_CATALOG  TABLE_SCHEMA  TABLE_NAME  COLUMN_NAME  ORDINAL_POSITION  COLUMN_DEFAULT